# Usage of the word “gratis”

Tags: word-usage

> 2 beers were gratis.

Is this the correct usage of the word gratis? A more common alternative is to say *2 beers were complementary*.

Any other ways to use *gratis*?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

'Gratis', a Latin word meaning (adjective) 'available without payment' or (adverb) meaning 'without asking for any payment' is, perhaps, a little old-fashioned in everyday usage, but reasonably common in business English. To say to a friend 'I'll drive you to the airport gratis' could sound formal and old-fashioned, and, depending on the hearer's level of education, might not be understood.

> **How to Use Complementary**
> The adjective "complementary" (with an "e" in
> the second syllable) means serving to complete or supply mutual needs.
> Two or more parts that come together to make a better whole are called
> complementary.
>
> Complementary acute angles, when added together, make a right or
> 90-degree angle. Complementary colors of light, when combined, produce
> colorless white light. Complementary objects go together: pen and
> paper, needle and thread, horse and carriage, bow and arrow.
>
> **How to Use Complimentary**
> The adjective "complimentary" (with an "i" in
> the second syllable) means flattering and favorable or given free as a
> courtesy. Derived from the noun "compliment," "complimentary" can be
> used to describe a person or an action by a person (a complimentary
> performance review means a positive performance review) or an item or
> service that is provided for no cost (complimentary tickets, often
> abbreviated to comp tickets, are free of charge).

[Complementary and Complimentary](https://www.thoughtco.com/complementary-and-complimentary-1689348)

> complementary adjective (GOOD TOGETHER)
> useful or attractive together

[Complementary (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complementary)

> complimentary adjective (FREE)
>
> If tickets, books, etc. are complimentary, they are given free,
> especially by a business.

[Complimentary (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complimentary)

Comment: Well, I think that's a pretty compelling reason for even some *native* speakers to avoid the ***complementary / complimentary*** minefield!

Comment: There's also the jokey expression [free, gratis and for nothing](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/free%2C+gratis%2C+and+for+nothing).

Answer (score 1):

The *most* common way to express OP's example is simply ***Two beers were free.*** As an alternative more specific to the *exact* context, they were ***on the house***.

***Complementary*** and ***gratis*** are pointless "affectations" that are unlikely to be good choices in a non-native speaker's utterances. The confusion generated by the ***complementary / complimentary*** minefield should be more than enough to dissuade you from using it!

Comment: 'Gratis' for 'free' is very old-fashioned and hardly used any more. 'Compl**e**mentary' used to mean 'free' or 'without charge' is a spelling error. The correct word is 'compl**i**mentary'.

Comment: The OP would also like to know how or in which situations to use the word *gratis* though. +1 for "it's on the house" where *house* stands for "public house" i.e. **the pub** but I suppose restaurants would also use this expression (but not 100% sure).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: For a non-Anglophone, the best answer to *How and where to use 'gratis'?* is ***Never, nowhere***. End of story.

Comment: So, gratis should never be said or used by a non-native speaker? Wow...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Actually, I think *you've* got the two spellings / meanings the wrong way round! I did think about mentioning the fact that those two are often "orthographically conflated" while I was composing my answer. I'm not bulletproof on that point myself, so I quickly googled it at the time. And decided not to mention it because it seemed OP had in fact got the *right* spelling! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: My feeling is anyone who feels the need to use a site like ELL to help them learn English shouldn't use it. That obviously doesn't include people like *you*, who primarily come here to *help* those people, rather than to learn English. I certainly wouldn't expect to see a question posted here by you asking how to use the word (but if you did, I probably wouldn't say ***never*** to you! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Google again! With 'e' in the second syllable - good together, with 'i' in the second syllable - without charge.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - your comment 'My feeling...' almost exactly reproduces what I would have said. If a person needs to ask (on here or elsewhere), they aren't ready to use that word.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I just looked at the first snippet on Google's home page after searching for **complimentary vs complementary** (where I only had to type the letter **v** after the first word; Google knew by then what I'd be asking! :). And I only looked at the first sentence: ***Complimentary** means “expressing a compliment” or “favorable.” It can also mean “free” in reference to items or services provided as a courtesy. **Complementary** refers to enhancing or emphasizing the qualities of another person or thing.* What a misleading definition!